# Is there any Option in Embarcadero Delphi Anchor Sides/AnchorToNeighbour

Tags: delphi, alignment, delphi-10-seattle, layout-anchor

Is there any Option in Embarcadero Delphi Anchor Sides/AnchorToNeighbour?

Currently, it is possible in Lazarus to anchor-align the components to Left-Right/Top Bottom etc to the neighboring components. I need some image screenshot or any functional way of achieving this in Delphi Seattle 10!!

Answer (score 1):

In VCL, there is nothing to automatically anchor a control relative to a neighboring control.  The `Anchors` property is meant for aligning a control relative to the edges of its `Parent`, not relative to other controls.  However, windowed controls (not graphical controls) have [`OnAlignInsertBefore`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnAlignInsertBefore) and [`OnAlignPosition`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnAlignPosition) events that can be used for custom alignment when the [`Align`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Align) property is set to `alCustom`.  Otherwise, you have to use `OnResize` event handlers to manually position/size controls as needed.

In FireMonkey, there are `TLayout`-derived components (`TFlowLayout`, `TGridLayout`, `TScaledLayout`) to help arrange components (see [Using Layouts to Arrange Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Layouts_to_Arrange_Components) for more details), but this does not necessary equate to anchoring a control to a neighboring control, it is still relative to the `Parent`, just a bit more flexible than what VCL offers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it and worked as expected. Howeer, I'm wondering why Lazarus and Embarcadero Delphi communities are going separate ways after DX7

Comment: Good suggestion. I also tried and checked TGridPanel and TFlowPanel and to some extent it helped me.